# Removing list format from cell in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm using pivot wider on some data below:

```
df <- structure(list(Gene.Symbol = c("DES", "AARS2", "ABCC9", "ABCC9", 
"ABCC9"), PanelApp = c("Arrhythmogenic cardiomyopathy", "Cardiomyopathies - including childhood onset", 
"Cardiomyopathies - including childhood onset", "Dilated cardiomyopathy - adult and teen", 
"Dilated Cardiomyopathy and conduction defects")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from=Gene.Symbol, 
    values_from = PanelApp) -> pa_wider
```

This gives me this output, but I'm ending up with lists printed:

```
pa_wider <- structure(list(DES = list(c("Arrhythmogenic cardiomyopathy", 
"Cardiomyopathies - including childhood onset"
)), AARS2 = list("Cardiomyopathies - including childhood onset"), 
    ABCC9 = list(c("Cardiomyopathies - including childhood onset", 
    "Dilated cardiomyopathy - adult and teen", "Dilated Cardiomyopathy and conduction defects"
    ))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

The output is as a list (c("value1", "value2")) and I instead want the cells to look like this (value1, value2):

```
structure(list(DES = ("Arrhythmogenic cardiomyopathy, Cardiomyopathies - including childhood onset"
), AARS2 = ("Cardiomyopathies - including childhood onset"), 
ABCC9 = ("Cardiomyopathies - including childhood onset, Dilated cardiomyopathy - adult and teen, Dilated Cardiomyopathy and conduction defects"
)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.frame"
))
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have and what you want. As is, the question is hard to understand.
You likely could get a better layout reviewing upstream transformations, it may be better to share the data as it was before the pivoting operation alongside a clear explanation of your goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to group by the gene and then summarize the PanelApp data using `paste0`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Gene.Symbol) %>% 
  summarize(PanelApp = paste0(PanelApp, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=Gene.Symbol, 
              values_from = PanelApp)
```

It looks hard to read though.  Is that what you want?